# Start Date Calculated Given End Date and Working Hours PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, plsql

Using Oracle PL/SQL I need to calculate a start date for a task using the due date and the working hours required to finish the task.

Given 24-JUL-2012 17:00 as a due date and 20 hours as hours needed to complete the task and using working hours of 8AM-5PM (1 hour lunch - so 8 hours per day max) I need to figure out in PL/SQL what the start date/time would be... which should come out to 22-JUL-2012 13:00.

Comment: We would need to know the time of the lunch hour. Does day of the week matter (only working Monday through Friday)? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @AdamHawkes Yes, only Monday through Friday. Lunch hours vary, but it doesn't really matter, just that the work per day doesn't go over 8 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code could be a starting point:

```
function task_start_date(
  p_due_date date,
  p_working_hours number
) return date
is
  l_start_date date;
begin
  -- Subtract full days
  l_start_date := p_due_date - trunc(p_working_hours / 8);
  -- Subtract remaining hours
  l_start_date := l_start_date - mod(p_working_hours, 8) / 24;
  -- Fix date if the due date is before 8AM
  if to_number(to_char(l_start_date, 'HH24')) < 8 then
    l_start_date := l_start_date - 15 / 24;
  end if;
  return l_start_date;
end task_start_date;
```

Note that the function does not consistently consider lunch time. You'll need to define exactly when lunch time is and adapt the function accordingly.

Comment: You sure there isn't a simple one-liner? :) I not concerned with the lunch time too much, and this code seems to work pretty well (further testing required)... but I don't really understand the code to fix the date if it is before 8AM. If it ends up starting before 8AM does it push it back a day? I don't understand what 15/24 is supposed to do.

Comment: Let's say the due date is July 24, 10:00 and 11 hours are required. Then I first subtract a day (8 hours) and then another 3 hours. The result is July 23, 7:00, which is before work starts that day. So I subtract another 15 hours (the time from 5PM until 8AM the next day). The result is July 22, 16:00.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. So I can just add some more if statements to determine if it falls on a Sat or Sun and then subtract 48/24 or 24/24 hours and push the start date back to Friday, correct?